# Taurus failed execute apachebenchmark on windows

Tags: multithreading, performance-testing, load-testing, apachebench, taurus

I'm using Winsows 7 and download latest Taraus installation, Download updated ApacheBenchmark from ApacheServer installation.

I'm trying execute ApacheBenchmark using Taraus's [Simplest working example](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ApacheBenchmark/)

Calling `bzt config.yaml` but failed with `Invalid number of requests`

> ```
> execution:
> - executor: ab
>   scenario: simple
>
> scenarios:
>   simple:
>     requests:
>     - http://blazedemo.com/
> ```

But failed

```
16:16:04 INFO: Preparing...

16:16:05 INFO: Starting...

16:16:05 INFO: Waiting for results...

16:16:06 INFO: Did not mute console logging

16:16:06 INFO: Waiting for finish...

16:16:06 WARNING: ab tool exited with non-zero code: 1

16:16:06 WARNING: Please wait for graceful shutdown...

16:16:06 INFO: Shutting down...

16:16:06 INFO: Post-processing...

16:16:06 INFO: Test duration: 0:00:01

16:16:07 ERROR: Child Process Error: Empty results, most likely simple (ApacheBenchmarkExecutor) failed. Actual reason for this can be found in logs under C:\Users\User\2018-12-06_16-16-04.160200

16:16:07 ERROR: ab STDERR:

Invalid number of requests
```

When I tried second example *Example of hold-for usage* taurus opened and crashed

Is there a taraus windows issue or known limitation? as I missing configuration/execution parameter?

- Note I uninstall old version before installing new version and config.yaml is a valid yaml file

ApacheBenchmark works as standalone for example when executing

```
ab http://blazedemo.com/
```

Error in verbose (-v)

```
[2018-12-13 08:31:46,400 DEBUG bzt.utils] Executing shell: ['ab', '-n', '0', '-c
', '0', '-d', '-r', '-l', '-g', 'Z:\\2018-12-13_08-31-45.916555\\ab.tsv', '-k',
'http://blazedemo.com/'] at Z:\
[2018-12-13 08:31:46,406 DEBUG Engine] Checking <bzt.modules.aggregator.Consolid
atingAggregator object at 0x0000000003D50F98>
[2018-12-13 08:31:46,407 DEBUG Engine.ab.TSVDataReader.FileReader] File not appe
ared yet: Z:\2018-12-13_08-31-45.916555\ab.tsv
[2018-12-13 08:31:46,408 DEBUG Engine.ab.TSVDataReader] Buffer len: 0; Known err
ors count: 0
[2018-12-13 08:31:46,409 DEBUG Engine.consolidator] Consolidator buffer[0]: dict
_keys([])
[2018-12-13 08:31:46,410 DEBUG Engine] Checking <bzt.modules.monitoring.Monitori
ng object at 0x0000000003D65CC0>
[2018-12-13 08:31:46,736 DEBUG Engine] Checking <bzt.modules.reporting.FinalStat
us object at 0x00000000045E5D68>
[2018-12-13 08:31:46,737 DEBUG Engine] Checking <bzt.modules.console.ConsoleStat
usReporter object at 0x00000000045D9CC0>
[2018-12-13 08:31:46,739 INFO Engine.console] Did not mute console logging
[2018-12-13 08:31:46,832 INFO Engine.console] Waiting for finish...
[2018-12-13 08:31:46,886 DEBUG Engine] Iteration took 0.488 sec, sleeping for 0.
512 sec...
[2018-12-13 08:31:47,400 DEBUG Engine] Checking <bzt.modules.provisioning.Local
object at 0x0000000003D1B400>
[2018-12-13 08:31:47,403 WARNING Engine.ab] ab tool exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taurus forum responded that it's a bug need to be fixed and suggested a workaround:

> Now you can use explicit concurrency and iterations as workaround:
>
> ```
> execution:
>  - executor: ab
>    iterations: 1
>    concurrency: 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine on my [Taurus version 1.13.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-open-source-taurus-1-13):

```
C:\temp>bzt -o modules.ab.path=c:/temp/ab.exe ab.yaml
17:19:41 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.13.1
17:19:41 INFO: Starting with configs: ['ab.yaml']
17:19:41 INFO: Configuring...
17:19:41 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\temp\2018-12-14_17-19-41.894000
17:19:41 INFO: Preparing...
17:19:42 WARNING: There is newer version of Taurus 1.13.2 available, consider upgrading. What's new: http://gettaurus.org/docs/Changelog/
17:19:42 INFO: Starting...
17:19:42 INFO: Waiting for results...
17:19:42 INFO: Did not mute console logging
17:19:42 INFO: Waiting for finish...
17:19:43 WARNING: Please wait for graceful shutdown...
17:19:43 INFO: Shutting down...
17:19:43 INFO: Post-processing...
17:19:43 INFO: Test duration: 0:00:01
17:19:43 INFO: Samples count: 1, 0.00% failures
17:19:43 INFO: Average times: total 0.000, latency 0.000, connect 0.000
17:19:43 INFO: Percentiles:
+---------------+---------------+
        | Percentile, % | Resp. Time, s |
        +---------------+---------------+
        |           0.0 |         0.253 |
        |          50.0 |         0.253 |
        |          90.0 |         0.253 |
        |          95.0 |         0.253 |
        |          99.0 |         0.253 |
        |          99.9 |         0.253 |
        |         100.0 |         0.253 |
        +---------------+---------------+
                17:19:43 INFO: Request label stats:
        +-----------------------+--------+---------+--------+-------+
                | label                 | status |    succ | avg_rt | error |
                +-----------------------+--------+---------+--------+-------+
                | http://blazedemo.com/ |   OK   | 100.00% |  0.000 |       |
+-----------------------+--------+---------+--------+-------+
        17:19:43 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\temp\2018-12-14_17-19-41.894000
17:19:43 INFO: Done performing with code: 0
```

It might be the case you're sitting on a buggy version, you can obtain Taurus v1.13.1 as simple as:

```
pip install bzt==1.13.1
```

---

Just in case there is [Taurus Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/codename-taurus) where you can reach Taurus developers and maintainers, the chance of getting more professional answer is much higher there.

Comment: Is the `-o` necessary if ab.exe is part of windows path?